# Are there lying or social desirability items in IPIP pool?

Tags: personality, social-desirability, ipip

Are there any lie or social desirable questions in the IPIP pool of 2600 question?

Can I construct psychometrically such a scale if it does not exists by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are IPIP self-deception and impression management scales presumably modelled on the similarly named Paulhus scales (reliabilities in brackets):

SOURCE: http://ipip.ori.org/newPASKey.htm#Self-Deception

#### SELF-DECEPTION [.80]

```
+ keyed 
    Always know why I do things.
    Just know that I will be a success.
    Know that my decisions are correct.
    Feel comfortable with myself.
    Like to take responsibility for making decisions.

– keyed 
    Am not always honest with myself.
    Sometimes have trouble making up my mind.
    Dislike myself.
    Worry about what people think of me.
    Have a low opinion of myself.
```

#### IMPRESSION-MANAGEMENT [.82]

```
+ keyed 
    Would never take things that aren't mine.
    Would never cheat on my taxes.
    Believe there is never an excuse for lying.
    Always admit it when I make a mistake.
    Rarely talk about sex.
    Return extra change when a cashier makes a mistake.
    Try to follow the rules.
    Easily resist temptations.
    Tell the truth.
    Rarely overindulge.

– keyed 
    Have sometimes had to tell a lie.
    Use swear words.
    Use flattery to get ahead.
    Am not always what I appear to be.
    Break rules.
    Cheat to get ahead.
    Don't always practice what I preach.
    Misuse power.
    Get back at others.
    Am likely to show off if I get the chance.
```

Comment: is there any norms for the answers?